# What is the gradient of the product of two vectors

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis, fluid-dynamics

How do I simplify $\vec{\nabla}\cdot(\vec{v}\vec{v})$? Here $\vec{\nabla}=\partial_{x}\hat{i}+\partial_{y}\hat{j}$ and $\vec{v}=u\hat{i}+v\hat{i}$.

Comment: Do you mean $\nabla(v\cdot v)$?

Comment: define $\vec v\vec v$ please